# A drag forumula which jumps 3 column in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

in Google Sheets, I need a drag formula in which row stays same but column number jumps 3 columns each time. For example:

=‘TEMMUZ 2022’!O3 then =‘TEMMUZ 2022’!O6 then =‘TEMMUZ 2022’!O9.

I couldn’t find a way. Most probably with an array formula but I am not good with them. Anyone has an idea? Thanks.

Also, here is a dummy data of what I want to do: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xvoT6nB90HsZnpf8W1p83_sG_7uoD8lzIaqIZ2wFqB0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: you want to drag below or to right ?

Comment: and where is located the first formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation, use a unique formula for all the 3 columns

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(VLOOKUP(TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(COUNTA( 'TEMMUZ 2022'!O3:O95)/3);3;ROW('TEMMUZ 2022'!A3)));{ROW('TEMMUZ 2022'!A3:A95)\'TEMMUZ 2022'!O3:O95};2;0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for all your replies. I want to drag down. Here is my progress;

I tried `=OFFSET('TEMMUZ 2022'!O$1,3*row()-1,)` but gave an error. My Google Sheet is in English but perhaps because of localization I decided to try, `=OFFSET('TEMMUZ 2022'!O$93;3*row()-1;)` - this didn't give error but cell stays empty. Then I tried `=OFFSET('TEMMUZ 2022'!O$93;3;)` - this gave the correct value but this is not working with drag down. Need to write 3-6-9 etc. manually.

Comment: I have updated my answer according to your spreadsheet

Comment: Hello Mike, thanks for updating. This unique formula worked. How can I limit the range? O3:O95 is for TEMMUZ and then I will have 'AGUSTOS 2022'!O3:95. After TEMMUZ O95, there are some sum rows which I don't want to be shown. That's why need to finish at 95.

Comment: to limit, try ` =ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(VLOOKUP(TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(COUNTA( 'TEMMUZ 2022'!O3:O95)/3);3;ROW('TEMMUZ 2022'!A3)));{ROW('TEMMUZ 2022'!A3:A95)\'TEMMUZ 2022'!O3:O95};2;0)))`  added in your spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

use instead of dragging:

```
=FILTER(O3:O; MOD(ROW(O3:O); 3)=0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @player0 unfortunately I didn't understand this solution. I appreciate your time for the answer.

Comment: @selimimre you asked for dragging formula that jumps every 3 rows. this answer provides non-dragging one-cell formula that outputs array of your O column while jumping every 3 rows.

Comment: You are correct @player0 however, the main reason for me for asking a dragging formula was that I wasn't aware about any array solution. I couldn't imagine such solution. With the limited range, I got the same result. In general, I would really like to learn/know dragging formula as well. But I couldn't make yours work. I am sorry.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate by multiple of 3 of row increment, which is what you implicitly asked for, you need [`index()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en)

Say your desired starting cell is `B2`, in `B2`, put

```
=index(‘TEMMUZ 2022’!O:O, (row(‘TEMMUZ 2022’!B2)-row(‘TEMMUZ 2022’!B$2))*3+1,1)
```

As you "drag", all non-fixed indices iterate. For example, when the formulate *spreads* to `B3`, all non-fixed rows increase by 1, because the difference between `B3` and `B2` is 1 row. So `‘TEMMUZ 2022’!B2` becomes `‘TEMMUZ 2022’!B3`. But `‘TEMMUZ 2022’!B$2` remains unchanged because of `$` makes the row index fixed.

The reference range for `index()` does not change because `O:O` does not reference any particular row.

The row index for `index()` increase by 3 because the times 3. Moreover, we need to reference the difference in row index between subsequent cells and the 1st row we started spreading the formulate with. Hence, instead of directly getting `row(B2)`, we use `row(B2)-row(B$2)`.

Column index for `index()` is 1 because we made the reference range `O:O` only and 1st column in `O:O` is column O. For your particular application, you may need to adapt your range and thus column index. For example, if you are referencing the whole sheet `A:Z`, you need the corresponding column offset, which is `column(O2)`.

Comment: Hello Argyll, thanks for the detailed explanation. However, I couldn't make it work. Here how I tried: http://recordit.co/i5M4EBRCtV

Comment: @selimimre: See edits. See if it is what you are looking for? Later, we should update your question to be clear that you don't necessarily start with the 1st row.

Comment: @selimimre: I also noticed you put the formula in `B2`. In that case, all your ranges should be moved accordingly. I'll edit my answer for now to show you what that means. I used cell `O1` (with letter O) in my answer because column O is in your question. We do need to be precise with the desire outcome when formulating our questions. We can revisit the editing of your question later.

Comment: Hello Argyll, thanks again for the detailed answers. I went with Mike's solution because it worked. I couldn't work your solution, however I am sure it is because of my less knowledge of such formulas then you guys. I appreciate your time.